# How to catalog my location to a specific zone on android

Tags: android, google-maps

I got the device location address, and now I want to catalog the address to a specific area, - such as down Town or west-side, that I pre-build before, and then to know with which area to work on.
I can`t use a radios "nearby" from the location because every area got a different size.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you "pre-built" your areas? What classifies them? Area? Initial lat/lng? Street names? There's not much info on your question so it's hard to help you.

Comment: @PedroOliveira, by saying "pre-built" I meant that I already catalog to city into 5 parts, that I want to work with. Nothing more..